# How do you pass Custom Dimension values to Google Tag Manager in Android NOT the web

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I am able to pass events to google Tag Manager v4 but the custom dimensions are not set.  I have not been able to find ANYTHING on examples how to do this. The custom dimensions are setup correctly.

the code I'm using is:

```
DataLayer mDataLayer = ContainerHolderSingleton.getDataLayer();
mDataLayer.pushEvent("clip-start",DataLyaer.mapOf("Network","network value here"));
```

It should be this simple.  I've setup the custom dimensions to be Custom Dimension index 1, in the admin it's setup as index 1.

Doesnt' help that googles sample code doesn't tell me much either: This is the generated code that is generated when I input the custom dimesnion in the admin. What is "tracker", or Fields.. they dont tell me which import will work with this.

```
String dimensionValue = "SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE";
tracker.set(Fields.customDimension(1), dimensionValue);
```

So ultimately, how do I pass the custom Dimension values through the data Layer to GTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to use the GoogleAnalytics Tracker like this:

```
tracker.set("&cd1", "new video title");
tracker.set("&cd2", "vidoe type");                
tracker.set("&cd3", "access");
```

&cd1, &cd2 etc is the way these constant fields are passing custom dimensions to the back end.

Make sure you double check the sample code for reusing and downloading a container. I had mucked with it and that was stopping me from getting the new container, thus also not getting new values. Copy the sample code verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you may not have added custom dimensions into your google analytics tag in tag manager.  Add the custom dimensions with parameters with values.  The ids should match the ones in analytics.

Hope that helps

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer to explain fellow programmers to understand how it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: The issue isn't in the code, it is in the setup of the analytics tag in tag manager.  You need to add the custom dimensions there. Not much else to say